# view_context equivalent in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Looking through Railscast 340, for DataTables/Will_paginate, the example uses view_context when initiating a new instance.

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

I've tried the same code to realize that Rails 2.3 does not have it.

According to the docs, the equivalent is

```
View.new[lookup_context, assigns, controller]
```

What does the lookup_context and assigns refer to? I've tried the following.

```
User.new(current_program.users, {}, self)
```

However, as expected, if I pass the above in, it will throw an unexpected error 3 for 1.

Comment: Do you really need to do this in Rails 2.3?? This version reached EOL on 2013-06-25 (almost 4 years ago!), when rails 4.0.0 was released. Figuring out how to mimic `view_context` will be the least of your problems in trying to maintain an application so out of date.

Comment: @TomLord Unfortunately, the stack that I'm stuck with is Rails 2.3 LTS

Comment: I am stuck with the same rails 2.3, did you find a solution?